# Testing a Post multipart/form-data request on REST Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've written a typical spring boot application, now I want to add integration tests to that application.

I've got the following controller and test:

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class PictureController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadpicture", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<VehicleRegistrationData> uploadPicturePost(@RequestPart("userId") String userId, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(sPicture.saveAndParsePicture(userId, file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
    @Test
public void authorizedGetRequest() throws Exception {
    File data = ResourceUtils.getFile(testImageResource);
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(data);


    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, bytes);

    MockMultipartFile userId =
            new MockMultipartFile("userId",
                    "userId",
                    MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
                    objectMapper.writeValueAsString("123456").getBytes()
            );
    this.mockMvc.perform(multipart("/uploadPicture")
            .file(userId)
            .file(file)
            .header(API_KEY_HEADER, API_KEY)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Testing the controller with the `OkHttp3` client on android works seamlessly, but I can't figure out how to make that request work on the `MockMvc`

I expect `200` as a status code, but get `404` since, I guess, the format is not the correct one for that controller

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 404 usually means that the URL is not correct. Can you try correcting the case in the test (uploadPicture vs uploadpicture)

Comment: @Vasco Thank you, I was just that blind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a typo.

In your controller, you claim the request URL to be `/uploadpicture`, but you visit `/uploadPicture` for unit test.